# How to deploy the Fluid server?

Tags: node.js, fluid-framework

I'm using the Fluid draft-js example here:
https://github.com/microsoft/FluidExamples/tree/main/draft-js

I know I can run the app locally by just running `npm start` or just the server by using `npm start:server`

But how can I deploy this app (server) to a production environment? (I'm sorry if this is a stupid question). Should I just upload the repository to a node environment and run the commands? Should I try to make a docker image?

Any ideas?

Comment: We currently don't have any documented workflows for standing up a server in production. The server packed with the application is Tinylicious and it's designed for localhost/testing scenarios. There is another fluid service called Routerlicious that is designed for deployed scenarios although we don't support it in any production capacity.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/server/routerlicious for documentation including how to build it as a Docker Image

Comment: There is also this blog that was written by one of the founders of Fluid about deploying the service. https://medium.com/@kurtberglund/deploy-and-run-your-own-fluid-framework-service-8c82294e74b7